# Failed to migrate orphaned documents in MongoDB sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb

I built a cluster with two shards (shard-A,shard-B) and I observed some error logs in the system log of mongod

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-06T22:06:30.639+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":5087102, "ctx":"migrateThread","msg":"Recipient failed to copy oplog entries for retryable writes and transactions from donor","attr":{"namespace":"<database>.<colllection>","migrationSessionId":"shard-B_shard-A_61ae895984ae400ff6c610bb","fromShard":"shard-B","error":"ExceededTimeLimit: Failed to delete orphaned <database>.<colllection> range [{ key: \"value1\" }, { key: \"value2\" }) :: caused by :: operation exceeded time limit"}}
```

Mongo version: 5.0.4
The entire cluster seems to be working properly, but I don’t know the reason for these error logs

Comment: `"s":"I"` means "severity = Informational", so I would not spent to much effort on it. Most likely the operation was re-done at next sharding round.

Comment: unfortunately, MongoDB [does NOT retry errors](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26380) due to ExceededTimeLimit code. did you find a way to fix it?